# Incoming!: How Can a Creature Get Out of Its Space as an Immediate Action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, magic-items, feats, equipment

## The Situation

The lone creature needs to occupy a different space--probably only once--, but it needs to be in that different space *now*, while it would normally be flat-footed, *after* an attack's made against it but *before* that attack's resolved.

The creature needs 2 things: it needs 1) to avoid being flat-footed 2) to occupy a different space before an attack resolves (probably *via* an immediate action or an off-turn non-action). Ideally, a cheap, slotless item exists for each but 1-3 feats or expensive items are acceptable alternatives.

### Binds

- More than a 5-ft. step is preferred, but 5-ft. steps are still awesome, thanks. Such options *must* note that the 5-ft. step is explicitly an *extra* 5-ft. step, though. Many feats don't note this (e.g. Evasive Reflexes (*ToB* 30), Orien Battle Stride (*Dra* 143), Pursue (*ECS* 58)) making it unclear if their mentioned 5-ft. steps are in addition to the single 5-ft. step the creature can make each round (*PH* 144). I'd prefer the handful of feats that grant explicitly *extra* 5-ft. steps (e.g. Sidestep (*MH* 28)) to avoid discussions of text over intent. A way to activate those effects off-turn remains necessary.
- Class levels are unacceptable unless the class level’s benefits grant equivalent or better bonuses than taking 2-4 additional monstrous Hit Dice.
- No custom magic items. Both spell completion and trigger items are fine.
- The spell *contingency* [evoc] (*PH* 213) and the feat Craft Contingent Spell (*CAr* 77) are unavailable.
- Sources limited to Wizards of the Coast material.

---

### Flat-footed Prevention

Here's what I found.

- The 3rd-level meditation Domain spell *that art thou* [div] (“The Mahasarpa Campaign Setting: A Campaign Option Web Enhancement for *Oriental Adventures*” 8 [here](https://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20011019a)) *via* wand (3rd-level spell at caster level 5) (112 gp 5 sp per charge), *via* wand and affected by the feat Extend Spell (*PH* 94) (3rd-level spell but 4th-level equivalent at caster level 7) (420 gp per charge), *via* spellcasting (*PH* 129) affected by the feat Persistent Spell (*CAr* 81) (3rd-level spell but 9th-level equivalent at caster level 17) (1,530 gp) and *Shalantha's delicate disk* [conj] (*LE* 33-4) (6th-level spell at caster level 11) (860 gp) (unsure if a persistent *that art thou* fits in a *disk* though), or *via* staff affected by the feat Persistent Spell (*CAr* 81) (3rd-level spell but 9th-level equivalent at caster level 17) (2,295 gp per charge +300 gp per masterwork quarterstaff; 4 lbs.).
- The feat Brand of the Nine Hells (Dispater) (*FC2* 81).
- The 8th-level time Domain et. al. spell *foresight* [div] (*PH* 233) *via* staff (8th-level spell at caster level 15) (1,800 gp per charge +300 gp per masterwork quarterstaff; 4 lbs.).

### Immediate Action Space-exiting

Here's what I found.

- The magic item *shadow cloak* (*DrU* 101) (5,500; 1 lb.).
- The conjurer specialist wizard’s supernatural ability abrupt jaunt (*PH2* 70).

Comment: “Class levels are unacceptable unless the class level’s benefits grant equivalent or better bonuses than taking 2-4 additional monstrous Hit Dice.” Which Type? And honestly, this is almost always true, particularly if that Type isn’t Dragon or Outsider. Class features are better than chassis. Furthermore: how much time prior to the event can effects that have durations be applied? If something allows this type of movement, but only for next several rounds, is that sufficient or not? Minutes? Hours? Days?

Comment: @KRyan The type that would boost the creature to the next CR. I know classes are *usually* better, but a lot can be gained from judicious application of monstrous HD with the right creatures. Lengthy durations preferred, but foes *aren't* stealthy--1 minute's sufficient.

Comment: I wrote this question before taking a more serious look at immediate actions [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35924/8610); that answer's correct, and what I wanted to do in this question isn't possible. I've nonetheless left the question here for those whose campaigns use immediate actions differently.

Answer (score 5):

The Greaves of Aundair (Forge of War, which is an Eberron book) let you use an immediate action to "immediately take a Move action", but you're dazed after you do it. I can't think of anything else that you haven't already listed short of using the custom item creation rules to try and build something special for this purpose.

Moving as an immediate action being so rare is one of the reasons Abrupt Jaunt is crazy awesome.

Answer (score 3):

#### Ultimate Protection Against Surprises

The dire tortoise (*Sandstorm*) gets the amazing ability to always act in the surprise round (even if there wouldn’t otherwise *be* a surprise round!); if you *polymorph* into one (it’s an Ex Special Attack, which *polymorph* explicitly grants; minimum 14th CL), you basically always get to act, period, yes, even then. *Polymorph any object* twice can get you the ability effectively permanently, unless dispelled (and you’d get to act before any attempt to do so!). Look into a wand of *polymorph* or a couple of scrolls of *polymorph any object*.

This flat-out gives you a **full turn** in which to do whatever you like about the impending attack. You can *greater teleport* or just walk, whatever.

#### Another Immediate-Action Movement Mode

The *flicker* mystery from *Tome of Magic* allows you to teleport as an immediate action for the next rounds/level; CL 10 will get you the minute you require. As a 3rd-level mystery, it can get stuck in a wand. It does say that if it is used in response to an attack, that attack still has a 50% chance of hitting you, so Abrupt Jaunt is far better in every way.

Comment: Yeah, the *flicker* mystery--along with the Tenebrous vestige that also grants it to any 5th-level binder with the right feat--was on my short list, but the only-50%-miss-chance forced its exclusion; that limitation was too severe, much like the leaping flame maneuver from *ToB*. Good call with the dire tortise, though. That's crazy.

Answer (score 3):

For the movement part, just use the Celerity spell from PHB2:

```
When you cast this spell, you can immediately take a standard action, 
as if you had readied an action. You can even interrupt another 
creature's turn when you cast this spell. However, after you take the 
standard action granted by this spell, you are dazed until the end of 
your next turn.
```

Maximum cheese in combination with stuff that gives you immunity to daze.

Comment: Not so many (any?) obvious immunity to daze options. What are you thinking?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question specifies 3.5 and "Class levels are unacceptable", but for posterity; someone may find this answer useful...

In *Pathfinder*, the *Gunslinger* class from *Ultimate Combat* gets an ability at level 1 called *Gunslinger's Dodge*:

> *Gunslinger's Dodge (Ex)*: At 1st level, the gunslinger gains an uncanny
>   knack for getting out of the way of ranged attacks. When a ranged
>   attack is made against the gunslinger, she can spend 1 grit point to
>   move 5 feet as an immediate action; doing so grants the gunslinger a
>   +2 bonus to AC against the triggering attack. This movement is not a 5-foot step, and provokes attacks of opportunity. Alternatively, the
>   gunslinger can drop prone to gain a +4 bonus to AC against the
>   triggering attack. The gunslinger can only perform this deed while
>   wearing medium or light armor, and while carrying no more than a light
>   load.

http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classes/gunslinger.html

Comment: ...And the feat Amateur Gunslinger (also from *Ultimate Combat*) allows the deed to be used by anyone. It's too bad it's just an AC bonus and not *at least* a miss chance, though.